# How to calculate the Fourier Transform of a solvable chaos waveform?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, parameter-estimation

Recently I am stucking in frequency estimation of a solvable chaos waveform.
Its local analytic expression in time domain is
$$
z(t)=s_m(u_m-s_m)e^{\beta(t-mT)}\cos(\omega_0 t+\varphi),mT\leq t<(m+1)T
$$
where $u_m \sim U(-1,1)$ , $s_m=sgn[u_m]$ and $s_m\in[+1,-1]$.
$T=2\pi/\omega_0$ and $\beta=T \mathrm{ln}2$. And $m = 0,1,2,...$.

And its waveform is shown in following ($\omega_0 = 200\pi$)
[image]

Its spectrum shows spikes at base frequency $f_0 =2\pi/\omega_0$ and its harmonics (here we set the base frequency as 100Hz). Besides, the spectrum has regularly repeated shape which implies some kind of determined solvable expression of Fourier Transform.

[image]

To begin with, I tried to calculate the FT directly, as
$$
Z(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty z(t)e^{j\omega t}\mathrm{d}t\\
=\sum_{m=-\infty} ^{\infty}s_m(u_m-s_m) \int_{mT}^{(m+1)T} e^{\beta(t-mT)}\cos(\omega_0 t+\varphi) e^{j\omega t}\mathrm{d}t\\
=\frac 1 2 \sum_{m=-\infty} ^{\infty}s_m(u_m-s_m) \int_{mT}^{(m+1)T} e^{\beta(t-mT)} \{e^{j[(\omega_0+\omega) t+\varphi]}+e^{-j[(\omega_0-\omega) t+\varphi]}\}\mathrm{d}t
$$

However, the integeration is limted in a window with width of $T$ and it is hard to calculate the FT from it.

Then I tried another way to prove the existence of spikes at base frequency and its harmonics. Here, I calcute the integration of $z(t)\sin(n\omega_0 t)$ as
$$
a_0(n\omega_0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty z(t)\sin (n\omega_0 t)\mathrm{d}t\\
=\sum_{m=-\infty} ^{\infty}s_m(u_m-s_m) \int_{mT}^{(m+1)T} e^{\beta(t-mT)}\cos(\omega_0 t+\varphi) \sin (n\omega_0 t)\mathrm{d}t\\
=\sum_{m=-\infty} ^{\infty}s_m(u_m-s_m) \int_{0}^{T} e^{\beta t}\cos(\omega_0 t+\varphi) \sin (n\omega_0 t)\mathrm{d}t\\
=\int_{0}^{T} e^{\beta t}\cos(\omega_0 t+\varphi) \sin (n\omega_0 t)\mathrm{d}t\sum_{m=-\infty} ^{\infty}s_m(u_m-s_m)
$$

where $n=1,2,3...$ .
And 
$$
b_0(n\omega_0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty z(t)\cos (n\omega_0 t)\mathrm{d}t\\
=\int_{0}^{T} e^{\beta t}\cos(\omega_0 t+\varphi) \cos (n\omega_0 t)\mathrm{d}t\sum_{m=-\infty} ^{\infty}s_m(u_m-s_m)
$$

And the amplitude of spectrum at $n\omega_0$ is 
$$
c(n\omega_0)=\sqrt{a_0(n\omega_0)^2+b_0(n\omega_0)^2}
$$

Still, it is difficult to prove the existence of delta funcions in the spectrum from the amplitude at base frequency.

Hence, how to prove the frequency properties shown in Figure 2 ? Is there any possiblity to calculate the FT of $z(t)$?

Comment: Interesting waveform, 1) What is $t$ and what is $m$? 2) $u$ has the deltas you are looking for. Am I right to assume that $u$ is a sequence of random step functions placed randomly in the time domain? Or is it meant to be [impulses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function)? 3) Multiplication in the time domain becomes something else in the frequency domain (?)...but that is not exactly visible here...

Comment: 1) $t$ means time, and $m$ is the index of the $m$th sign $S_m$ and $u_m$. 2)$u_m$ is a random number uniformly occuring from -1 to 1. $S_m$ is the sign of $u_m$. And $u_m$ admits a kind of iteration function with $u_{m-1}$. 3) There exists some repeated similar sections in time domain, but I don't know whether it has any relations with the spikes in frequency domain. Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I totally misunderstood $u$, do you have a reference for this equation? It looks like a driven damped oscillator that is driven by random impulses (?). What do you mean *"...a kind of iteration function with $u_{m-1}$..."*? Where does $u_{m-1}$ appear?

Comment: The original idea is to conduct frequency estimation of a solvable chaos system proposed in [A matched filter for chaos](
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/44887296_A_matched_filter_for_chaos
) . $z(t)$is an absolute-valued envelope of equation (15) in this article. And $z(t)=|u(t)|-1$.
The iteration function is shown in equation (16)  in that reference.

Comment: The signal that you have is one _realization_ of a non-WSS random process and there is no guarantee that the Fourier transform of this particular realization exists in the conventional sense (finite-energy signals), or for that matter, in the generalized sense (power signals) where impulses are allowed in the spectrum.  You could try the usual tricks to convert the process into a WSS process and then compute its PSD as the Fourier transform of its autocorrelation function if that would be satisfactory to you.